# What is the best C# font selection control?

Tags: c#, winforms, fonts

To start off with, a little context for the question...

I have a C# .NET 2.0 program that generates web pages...  I am looking for a control that allows the user to pick web friendly fonts for use in generating the web page to run on as many computer as possible.  I'm currently useing the MS font dialog, but I have not found a way to filter it's list of fonts available.  Additionally, I wouldn't mind buying a control if it has a more attractive use interface...

So...  What font selection/picking control do you feel is the best and what attributes stand out for your choice?

Answer (score 2):

My favorite is available through [DevExpress.com](http://www.devexpress.com/). Their [ExtraEditors](http://www.devexpress.com/Help/?document=XtraEditors) library has a FontEdit component. Also if you embrace their controls it will improve the overall appearance of you app.

http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Editors/

Comment: I have read the documentation and the editor only allows selection of the font family.  It does not allow underline, bold, italics or the size to be changed.  Nor did I see a way to filter the font selection, but perhaps I missed something in the online documentation?

Comment: DevExpress doesn't have an out-of-the-box FontEditor control that lets you modify all of those aspects of the font, but as Jamey alluded to, if you have the Full XtraEditor Suite, you can utilize the FontEdit component to create a custom dialog that includes whatever font properties you want (bold, italic, Web only, etc.)